# Bordermatrix doesn't seem to work

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mathjax

Help of the Cross Validated says that "Cross Validated uses MathJax to render LaTeX." and the "Learn more" link leads to [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) site, where (under the Matrices point) [you can find](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node25.html#SECTION00088000000000000000) an example for `bordermatrix`, so I thought it means that it is supported. Yet, it doesn't seem to work, even if I directly copy the example there, it gives an error (`misplaced &`):

$$\bordermatrix{\text{corner}&c_1&c_2&\ldots &c_n\cr
                r_1&a_{11} &  0  & \ldots & a_{1n}\cr
                r_2& 0  &  a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n}\cr
                r_3& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\cr
                r_4& 0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}}$$

Comment: I'd advise to to consult [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?r=SearchResults&s=8|37.3637).  MathJax is not equivalent to LaTeX, though it is largely based on LaTeX.  You can also search math.meta.stackexchange.com for questions asked about mathjax.  If you can't find anything resembling what you want to do, you can ask on that site for suggestions of how to do so using mathjax.

Comment: @JedrekMansfield Thanks! I checked it, I don't seem to be able to find `bordermatrix` there. Is it some kind of an official reference? I mean, does the lack of `bordermatrix` in that list officially means that is it unsupported...? (Contrary to the link provided under Help!)

Comment: The link you are given is to a more exhaustive format, TeX.  There are work-arounds in mathjax, but MathJax does not support all that TeX nor all that LaTeX supports.  There is an SE site dedicated to TeX and LaTeX.  You might want to ask there, but I'm not sure how much they deal with MathJax.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. In that case it is somewhat misleading that this site is referred by the Help, what you linked would be much more helpful!

Comment: And I think I also found the "official" answer: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2031 ...

Answer (score 2):

As per the official site of MathJax, it indeed [seems to be](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2031) unsupported. This is discussed on several Stack Exchange sites as well, with workarounds (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888339/alternative-to-bordermatrix-for-mathjax) or [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/bordermatrix-in-mathjax) or [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/809/bordermatrix-in-mathjax)).

So there are two issues here, a feature request, but it is already done in the linked places, and a different problem, namely that Cross Validated's help refers to a generic TeX page, instead of a MathJax page, which is not really fortunate as they're far from being equivalent. More then that, it is also quite misleading, as the link's caption literally says: "Learn more: MathJax help" (and leads to a TeX site!).

Comment: For the latter request, I'd suggest you post on CrossValidated's meta site; in that way, more attention will be drawn to your request to revise, and perhaps replace the "help" link provided, with https://github.com/mathjax/

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just about to ask if I need to post it anywhere else after all :) I just did it: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/misleading-link-about-mathjax-help . Thanks again!

Comment: @TamasFerenci It would be very welcomed if you post it on [Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/) as well. If you do not, I would post it myself in a couple of days. Anyway, really great find!

Comment: @AntonMenshov Sure! I just did it: https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/misleading-link-about-mathjax-help .